# gulp default task isn't working when I set to default

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm following along with this video, the code of gulp is working in the video, but I'm facing issues:

**when I run `gulp` and I set gulp to default, but this is the log:**

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.2
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! missing script: default

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2019-12-29T00_42_33_080Z-debug.log
me@vlife:gulf$ npm run gulp
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.2
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> gulp-project@1.0.0 gulp /home/me/codedir/gulf
> gulp default

assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/home/me/codedir/gulf/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/home/me/codedir/gulf/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/codedir/gulf/gulpfile.js:23:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gulp-project@1.0.0 gulp: `gulp default`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gulp-project@1.0.0 gulp script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2019-12-29T00_42_44_118Z-debug.log
```

***package.json:***

```
{
  "name": "gulp-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "gulp": "gulp default"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

***Code:***

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let uglifycss  = require('gulp-uglifycss');


// sass.compiler = require('node-sass');


gulp.task('sass', () => {
    return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('./css/*.css')
      .pipe(uglifycss({
        "uglyComments": true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('run', ['sass', 'css']);

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./css/*.css', ['css'])
});


gulp.task('default', ['run', 'watch']);
```

Comment: The video must be using gulp v3, and you are using v4.  Search for how to migrate from gulp v3 to v4.

Comment: @unsle can you share the video with us?

Answer (score 1):

> I also interface this problem and even it has been fixed

```
gulp.task('default', ['run', 'watch']);
```

> gulp.parallel()

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('run', 'watch') );
```